# Return only certain rows when reading a DataFrame from SQL

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to read part of an SQL table into a pandas dataframe using SQLAlchemy, but I can't seem to find how to run the equivalent of a pandas filter at the time the table is read. I don't want to have to read the whole table and then filter, that seems like a waste of memory.

Just using pandas I would do:

```
list_of_codes_to_filter = ['code1', 'code2']
df = read_csv('path/to/file')
df = df[df['code'].isin(list_of_codes_to_filter)
```

Is there a simple equivalent using pandas read_sql? I'm trying something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///path_to_db')
connection = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql(select().where('code'.isin(list_of_codes_to_filter)), connection)
```

Comment: can we not filter the sql query itself? and then read it in through pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<tip>
Use `read_sql_query()` instead of `read_sql()`. According to the [documentation for read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

"This function is a convenience wrapper around read_sql_table and read_sql_query (for backward compatibility)."
</tip>

You're on the right track. You can create a SQLAlchemy Core query and pass that to `read_sql_query()` like so:

```py
codes_tbl = Table("codes", MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
list_of_codes_to_filter = ["code1", "code2"]
qry = select(codes_tbl).where(codes_tbl.c.code.in_(list_of_codes_to_filter))
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)
    """ SQL emitted:
    SELECT codes.id, codes.code 
    FROM codes 
    WHERE codes.code IN (?, ?)
    [generated in 0.00095s] ('code1', 'code2')
    """
    print(df)
    """ console output:
       id   code
    0   1  code1
    1   2  code2
    """
```

Complete MCVE [here](https://pastebin.com/CEmZ8hNt).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to manually define `Table`? Part of the point of using pandas+SQL was so that I don't have to manually write down all the row/columns names of the data tables. Pandas can already just read a whole table into a dataframe without me having to tell it all the metadata.

Comment: You don't have to "tell it all the metadata", `autoload_with=engine ` retrieves it for you.

Comment: Sorry, last comment was based on a misreading of your answer.